# Show files where grep wasn't found?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, grep

Here's my current code:

```
grep -o -P '(?<=class\=\"name\">).*?(?=<\/div>)' * > ../name.txt
```

Right now this is searching every file in a directory and outputting the name that's between `class="name">` and `</div>`.

But if nothing is found in a file, that file doesn't show up at all in the outputted `name.txt` file.

If the string cannot be found, is there a way for it to still show that file was searched?

For example, right now it's output like this:

```
file1.html:Bob
file3.html:Person
file4.html:Other
```

I want it to output like this:

```
file1.html:Bob
file2.html:UNKNOWN
file3.html:Person
file4.html:Other
```

Is this possible to do or am I missing something?

Comment: `P` doesn't appear to be a `grep` flag.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard It's a non-standard flag that means to use the PCRE engine.

Comment: @JackHasaKeyboard: on Mac the `-P` option doesn't exist...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write a loop that reports the files that don't have a match.

```
for file in *; do
    grep -h -o -P '(?<=class\=\"name\">).*?(?=<\/div>)' "$file" || echo "$file:UNKNOWN"
done
```